# Pretty printing polynomials with dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, polynomials

I'm struggling to create the `__ str __` function (aka pretty print) with polynomials, where dictionaries are used to contain the powers as keys and the elements as coefficients. I have done it with lists but I haven't mastered dictionaries yet. Is there anything to improve?

You can see in the second polynomial that if my last constant is not a constant, after arranging the keys with the `reverse()` function, the plus is always there, what can i do to prevent that? By the way I am trying to overload operators, after I've done this I'll try to do `__ add__`, `__ mul__`, `__ sub__`, and `__ call__`... though I would finish this one first :P

```
class Polynomial(object):                                
  def __init__(self, coefficients):
    self.coefficients = coefficients

  def __str__(self):
     polyd = self.coefficients
     exponent = polyd.keys()  
     exponent.reverse()          
     polytostring = ' '
     for i in exponent:
        exponent = i
        coefficient = polyd[i]
        if i == 0:
            polytostring += '%s' % coefficient
            break
        polytostring += '%sx^%s + ' % (coefficient, exponent)


     return polytostring


dict1 = {0:1,1:-1}
p1 = Polynomial(dict1)

dict2 = {1:1,4:-6,5:-1, 3:2}
p2 = Polynomial(dict2)

print p1
print p2
```

Comment: what should be accepted output for print statements ? (:P)

Comment: `exponent.reverse()` is not enough... Take note that the `keys` of a dictionary are not returned in any particular order.  What you want is instead `exponent.sort(reverse=true)`

Comment: By `exponent = i` in the loop, you're throwing away the content of the `exponent` list... is this what you _really_ want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove **break** statement because `for` loop will end(break) when exponent value is equal to `0`.

code:

```
class Polynomial(object):                                
    def __init__(self, coefficients):
        self.coefficients = coefficients

    def __str__(self):
        polytostring = ' '
        for exponent, coefficient in self.coefficients.iteritems():
            if exponent == 0:
                polytostring += '%s + ' % coefficient
            else:
                polytostring += '%sx^%s + ' % (coefficient, exponent)

        polytostring = polytostring.strip(" + ")

        return polytostring


dict1 = {0:1, 1:-1}
p1 = Polynomial(dict1)

dict2 = {1:1, 4:-6, 5:-1, 3:2}
p2 = Polynomial(dict2)

print "First:-", p1
print "Second:-", p2
```

Output:

```
$ python poly.py 
First:- 1 + -1x^1
Second:- 1x^1 + 2x^3 + -6x^4 + -1x^5
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this seems to work, if I understand your problem:

```
def format_term(coef, exp):
    if exp == 0:
        return "%d" % coef
    else:
        return "%dx^%d" % (coef, exp)

def format_poly(d):
    items = sorted(d.items(), reverse=True)
    terms = [format_term(v,k) for (k,v) in items]
    return " + ".join(terms)

dict1 = {0:1,1:-1}
print(format_poly(dict1))    # -1x^1 + 1

dict2 = {1:1,4:-6,5:-1, 3:2}
print(format_poly(dict2))    # -1x^5 + -6x^4 + 2x^3 + 1x^1
```

It just sorted the (key,val) pairs by key, then formats each term, and joins the terms into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

This is ***compact***

```
def __str__(self):return"".join("%+gx^%d"%(self.coefficients[e],e)for e in sorted(self.coefficients.keys(),reverse=1))
```

and works...

---

Let's have a look at the expression that is `return`ed, a piece at a time

```
"".join(...)
```

One of the string methods is [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.join) that accepts a sequence of strings and joins them with the (in this case) null string, e.g.

```
" + ".join(["a", "b", "c"] => "a + b + c"
```

In our case the argument of `join` is

```
"%+gx^%d"%(self.coefficients[e],e)for e in sorted(self.coefficients.keys(),reverse=1)
```

that, parenthesized, is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), that, btw, is similar to an implicit `for` loop.

On the right there is

```
for e in sorted(self.coefficients.keys(),reverse=1))
```

that assign to the local variable `e`, in turn, the `keys` of `self.coefficients` in sorted and reversed order

and on the left there is the result of the generator expression, evaluated for each possible value of `e`

```
"%+gx^%d"%(self.coefficients[e],e)
```

The expression above is known as [string *formatting* or *interpolation*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)
and works like this,

1. the string on the left is a *format string* and the parts in it prefixed by `%` are _format specifiers, here `%+g` means *generic* formatting always prefixed by the sign and `%d` means *integer digit*, whats outside (here `x^``) is copied vebatim into the result,
2. the `%` in the middle is the *formatting operator* itself
3. the tuple `(self.coefficients[e], e)` is the argument of the format string, you mnust have a 1 to 1 correspondance between format specifiers and arguments

At this point we have all the pieces in place... in a more colloquial form it could be

```
def __str__(self):
    # generated a correctly sorted list of exponents
    exps = sorted(self.coefficients.keys(),reverse=True)
    # generate a corretctly sorted list of coefficients
    coefs = [self.coefficients[e] for e in exps]
    # generate a list of formatted strings, one for each term
    reps = [ "%+gx^%d" % (c, e) for c, e in zip(coefs, exps)]
    # join the formatted strings
    poly_rep = "".join(reps)
    # let's end this story
    return poly_rep
```